# Difference between two 12V PWM signals/circuits (PIC and NE555)

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pwm, 555

I'm trying to understand the difference between two 12V PWM circuits I've build and tried.

The PWM signal is intended to control the speed of a motor. Only not in the way you would expect. The motor has its own circuitry and accepts the PWM signal as a speed control. So its not driving the motor directly.

To make this work I've tried two PWM control circuits:

I got a PIC to generate a PWM signal. I tried both the build-in ECCP module and software PWM.
I used the following circuit to convert the PWM from 5V to 12V.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f2mT7w.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Although this produces a very nice 12V signal the motor doesn't react to it all.

So I tried an old fashion NE555 in astable mode to generate the PWM.
[image: NE555 PWM circuit]

*Schematic from [DPRG](http://www.dprg.org/tutorials/2005-11a/)*

This circuit also puts out a nice 12V PWM signal with the same frequency and duty cycle as the PIC circuit. But this signal actually does have effect on the motor.

So my question is: **What is the difference between the PWM signals generated by these two circuits/devices?** By knowing this, I hope I can change the PIC circuit in such a way that motor reacts to it aswell .

Since I rather control the motor with the PIC, as this will make for a more compact end result.

**ADDITIONAL INFO:**
Both signals when connected to the motor.

PIC signal (without R2), 8.2-11.2V:
[image]

NE555 signal, varies 0-12.2V for 500ms and 0-1.32v for 780ms:
[image]

In both cases the PWM frequency and duty cycle remain intact, disregarding the voltages.

Comment: In the first schematic, your output is either high or floating. Add a pull-down resistor to the output and see what effect it has on your PWM fan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of R2 in the first circuit? It's limiting the maximum current to the motor to 12V/220Ω = 54.5mA, which is probably not enough.

Just connect the motor directly to the collector of Q2.

You also need a couple of other changes: put a resistor (e.g., 4700Ω) between the MCU output and the base of Q1; otherwise, the B-E junction of Q1 looks pretty uch like a dead short to ground to the MCU. Similarly, you need a resistor (about 1200Ω) between the collector of Q1 and the base of Q2; without it, when Q1 switches on, it basically shorts the 12V supply to ground via the B-E junction of Q2. 1200Ω limits the base drive to Q2 to about 10mA, which should be plenty.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will try and remove the resistor, it could be the cause. About the additional resistors you mentioned. If I'm correct the transistors I use (BCR503 & BCR583) have built in resistors that do the job.

Comment: I tried removing R2. The motor still does not respond. If I inspect what happens to the PWM signals when connected to the motor I notice that the "PIC-signal" changes to a 8.2-11.2V signal (Freq and DC remain intact). While the "555-signal" changes in a astable signal going from 0-12.2V for 500ms and then 0-1.32V for 780ms (Freq and DC remain intact).

Comment: OK, I didn't know those two transistors had built-in resistors. You need to show that in your schematic. But that's probably the problem: The 10K resistors in the BCR583 limit the base drive to about 1 mA, which in turn is going to limit the available collector current to about 70-100 mA. In other words, you aren't going to be able to saturate this transistor (Q2) and allow it to deliver the 500 mA it's capable of.

Comment: Yes you're right, I added the build-in resistors in the original schematic ;)! Is it worth trying changing the BCR583 with something like a PMBT2907A and adding a resistor (+-1200Ω) between the collector of Q1 and the base of Q2?

Comment: Tried it, same result...

Comment: I only just now noticed that in your second circuit, you're using pin 7 of the 555 as the output signal, which is an open-collector (NPN, to ground) output. How exactly do you have the motor wired up to each circuit? For the second circuit, you would have to have the other end connected to +12V. But the first circuit has an open collector with a PNP, to +12V configuration, for which the other end of the motor would have to be connected to ground.

Comment: Well since the PWM signal is only a speed control. The motor has it own +12v supply and GND (of course shared with the control circuit). Unfortunately I have no idea how the circuitry inside the motor handles things exactly. It is designed to accept speed control using PWM (10-1000Hz). However the way the PWM signal is generated maybe still could have something to do with it?

Comment: OK, in that case, the original circuit was probably fine. The only problem was the output wiring. You just needed to connect the bottom end of R2 to ground and take the output at the junction of R2 and Q2's collector.

Comment: That works! I left the PMBT2907A+1200Ω as it was (probably works with BCR583 in place too), added a 220R resistor as R2, connected it to ground and pulled the output from the junction between Q2 and R2. What did we change exactly? Reproducing the open-collector setup, as with the second circuit? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, except that it's upside-down with respect to the second circuit. The 555 has an NPN transistor that pulls to ground, and the external resistor provides the pullup to +12V. In the first circuit, the PNP pulls up to +12V and R2 provides the pulldown to ground. In fact, you could have done this with just one transistor: connect the right side of R5 directly to +12V and take the output at the collector of Q1. But the PWM signal would be inverted with this setup, which could be compensated for in the PIC firmware.